# How does さっきまで = "as before" in さっきまでと同じ部屋

Tags: translation, word-choice, hiragana

As the title explains, how does さっきまでと in

> さっきまでと同じ部屋 .

mean "as before" in English?

(I know that all together from the context of the sentences that come before and after さっきまでと同じ部屋 that the sentence roughly translates to "[It was/is the] same room as before." but I don't know where the "before" comes from).

Answer (score 3):

I think さっきまで means' just a while ago/Until just now/just until now. '

> **さっきまで**家で寝ていました。
>   I was sleeping at home just until now.
>
> **さっきまで**は泣いてたけど、今は元気です。
>   Until just now, I had been crying but now I'm fine.
>
> **さっきま**でと同じ部屋
>   [It was/is the] same room just a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to scarlet witch's answer.

The まで is the regular adverbial particle, which I think you may have recognized.  I'm guessing here, but it seems that your confusion stems from misparsing さっき.

さっき is a kind of emphasized form of さき, i.e. 先.  The "regular" form さき expresses a broad array of meanings, one of which is "earlier".  The geminate form さっき seems to be restricted in meaning, and is specifically about time, expressing something more like "just a little bit ago".